# How to take a DIRECTORY as input and process all files inside it one by one in HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read a directory using html and take all files inside it and show the content of every file into a text area one by one on click of next button. Please help me. I have written only below lines of code. please check.

```
<form id="browse" autocomplete="on" method="post"> . <div id=formdowntable></div>
<div id="errtxt"></div>';
<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple id="file"/>
<br><p align=center><input type="button" value="NEXT" onclick="next_action();"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Its not sufficient to solve your issue. add javascript code also

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE On click of next button call readFile function with iteration i instead of for loop.*
Wait till file gets loaded

```js
var $list = $('#list_of_files');

$('#file_input').change(function(event) {
    var listOfFiles = event.target.files;

    for (var i = 0, l = listOfFiles.length; i < l; ++i) {
    readFile(listOfFiles[i])
     // $list.append($('<p>'+  +'</p>'));
    }
});

function readFile(file){
if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        document.getElementById("fileContents").innerHTML = evt.target.result;
    }
    reader.onerror = function (evt) {
        document.getElementById("fileContents").innerHTML = "error reading file";
    }
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file_input" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="" directory="" />
<div id="list_of_files">
   <span id="fileContents"></span> 
</div>
```